# Tkinterのモジュールエラーを解消したい

Tags: python, tkinter

時計アプリを作成するのに、Tkinterをimportしたいです。

Anacondaはインストール済みなのですが、以下のコードに対してエラー(No module named 'Tkinter')が出てしまいます。

ご教授いただけば幸いです、よろしくお願いいたします。

```
        # coding: utf-8
        import Tkinter
        import math, time

        # メインウィンドウ
        root = Tk()
        root.title(u'時計')
        root.minsize(100, 100)
        root.maxsize(400, 400)

        # グローバル変数
        width = 140
        sin_table = []
        cos_table = []
        backboard = []

        # キャンバス
        c0 = Canvas(root, width = 140, height = 140, bg = 'darkgreen')
        c0.pack(expand = True, fill = BOTH)

        # 図形の生成
        circle = c0.create_oval(5, 5, 135, 135, fill = 'darkgray', outline = 'darkgray')
        for i in range( 12 ):
            backboard.append(c0.create_line(i, i, 135, 135, width = 2.0))
        hour = c0.create_line(70, 70, 70, 30, fill = 'blue', width = 3.0)
        min  = c0.create_line(70, 70, 70, 20, fill = 'green', width = 2.0)
        sec  = c0.create_line(70, 70, 70, 15, fill = 'red')

        # データの初期化
        def init_data():
            for i in range(720):
                rad = 3.14 / 360 * i
                sin_table.append(math.sin(rad))
                cos_table.append(math.cos(rad))


        # 背景の描画
        def draw_backboard():
            r = width / 2
            # 円
            c0.coords(circle, 5, 5, width - 5, width - 5)
            # 目盛
            for i in range(12):
                n = i * 60
                x1 = r + (r - 5) * sin_table[n]
                y1 = r + (r - 5) * cos_table[n]
                x2 = r + (r - 5) * 4 / 5 * sin_table[n]
                y2 = r + (r - 5) * 4 / 5 * cos_table[n]
                c0.coords(backboard[i], x1, y1, x2, y2)

        # 針を描く
        def draw_hand():
            t = time.localtime()
            r = width / 2
            rs = r * 7 / 8
            rm = r * 6 / 8
            rh = r * 5 / 8
            # 秒
            n = t[5] * 12
            x = r + rs * sin_table[n]
            y = r - rs * cos_table[n]
            c0.coords(sec, r, r, x, y)
            # 分
            n = t[4] * 12
            x = r + rm * sin_table[n]
            y = r - rm * cos_table[n]
            c0.coords(min, r, r, x, y)
            # 時
            h = t[3]
            if h >= 12: h -= 12
            n = h * 60 + t[4]
            x = r + rh * sin_table[n]
            y = r - rh * cos_table[n]
            c0.coords(hour, r, r, x, y)

        # 大きさの変更
        def change_size(event):
            global width
            w = c0.winfo_width()
            h = c0.winfo_height()
            if w < h:
                width = w
            else:
                width = h
            draw_backboard()
            draw_hand()

        # 表示
        def show_time():
            draw_hand()
            root.after(1000, show_time)

        # バインディング
        root.bind('<Configure>', change_size)

        # データの初期化
        init_data()

        # 最初の起動
        draw_backboard()
        show_time()

        # メインループ
        root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python2`ですか？
`import Tkinter`
これを、
`import Tkinter as Tk`
と変更。

`python3`なら
`Tkinter`ではなく、`tkinter`のようです。私は３なのでtkinterじゃないと動きません。

`Tk`,`Canvas`,`Both`,等の前に、
`Tk.Tk()`,`Tk.Canvas`,`Tk.Both`,というふうにつけましょう。
そうしたら動きましたよ。

Comment: Haru様、ご回答ありがとうございます。試してみたらうまくいきました。素早いご回答誠にありがとうございました。感謝いたします。